# How to set a bootstrap favicon in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, font-awesome, favicon

I'm trying to make rails app and I need to set a favicon using bootstrap and font_awesome5_rails gems with 'fa_icon()'. I know how to display an icon using that, but I don't know how to set it as a favicon. Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://gauger.io/fonticon/ test it out

Answer (score 0):

I'm using

> gem 'font-awesome-rails', '~> 4.7.0'

and

> gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.0'

rename your `application.css` to >> `application.css.scss`
in folder `app/assets/stylesheets`
and add this lines to this file

```
*= require font-awesome
*= require_self
*/

@import "bootstrap";
```

You can remove bootstrap if you don't need this.
After that check in rails template that it's working fine

```
<%= fa_icon('cog') %>
```